# Why can a public type throw an error that is a private type?

Tags: swift, private, public, access-control

Why does this code compile?

```
// ===============
// MyStruct.swift
// ===============    

private enum MyError: Error {
    case unexpectedError
}    

public struct MyStruct {
    static func throwError() throws {
        throw MyError.unexpectedError
    }
}    

// ===============
// main.swift
// ===============    

do {
    try MyStruct.throwError()
}
catch {
    print(error) // "unexpectedError"
}
```

The [documentation on access control](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) is very clear that we cannot *return* a private type in a public type member:

> A function can’t have a higher access level than its parameter types and return type

The previous statement seems obvious to me, and the following example shows how it won't compile (we're now returning it instead of throwing it):

```
private enum MyError: Error {
    case unexpectedError
}    

public struct MyStruct {

    // Note: we are now returning `MyError` instead of throwing
    static func returnError() -> MyError { // Error: Method must be declared fileprivate because its result uses a private type
        return MyError.unexpectedError
    }
}
```

What doesn't seem obvious to me, and is not mentioned in the documentation, is why can we *throw* this private type (`MyError`) in a method of a public type (`MyStruct`).

Comment: I'll make this a comment since I don't know the underlying details enough but in the case of throwing, `MyError` is not exposed publicly. You can't use `catch MyError.unexpectedError` since it's not public. Since all the `throws` exposes is an `Error`, there isn't an issue. But with the `return` you are explicitly attempting to expose the `MyError` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily return something of a private type

```
private enum MyError : Error {
  case unexpectedError
}

public struct MyStruct {
  static func myError() -> Error {
    return MyError.unexpectedError
  }
}
```

...by hiding it as a value of a not-so-private type. It's just subtyping. Or: `unexpectedError` is of type `MyError`, but it is *also* an `Error`. You can't expose the *type* `MyError`, but you can do whatever you want with its values, as long as you don't tell anyone anything more specific than "these are `Error`s".

Similarly, you can easily throw something of a private type

```
public struct MyStruct {
  static func throwError() throws {
    throw MyError.unexpectedError
  }
}
```

because `throw` wants an `Error`, you are giving it a `MyError`, and `MyError : Error`. The `throws` annotation itself says nothing about `throwError` throwing `MyError`s; it just says it may throw `Error`s in general.

Comment: I realized this after going to bed, so obvious! Thank you! Your explanation is simple and clear.